# Should an API return NULL for an int parameter? + How to handle

Tags: objective-c, ios, api, rest

At the moment our API is returning `NULL` for any `int` parameters which don't have a value.

e.g. In our user api one of our parameters looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    "user_id":NULL
    ...
}
```

I understand this can't be `0` as that could be a valid response, but having a `NULL` pointer is causing all sorts of issues because `int`s can't be `NULL` pointers.

My thought was that these values should be left out altogether - then they would return `nil` values (in objective c, e.g. `[dictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"] == nil`) which seems more appropriate, and isn't checking for a null pointer (which seems wrong, there is a difference between an int and a pointer).

Otherwise, a work around would be to make it into an `NSNumber` object which requires a pointer and can therefore be `NULL`. Then I can do something like:

```
NSNumber *userID = [dictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"];
if(userID != [NSNull null]){
  // its not null
}
```

But to me this feels fundamentally wrong, and the `NSNumber` documentation says things like:

> Note that number objects do not necessarily preserve the type they are created with.

This also makes me feel dirty.

(Then again, I'm initialising `NSDecimalNumber`s with strings... so I don't know why this would bother me...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "API" is expected to return an `int`, then it should never return NULL. Like you already said, you could use `NSNumber`, in that case you could return NULL. When talking about `int`, `NSNumber` will not come with loss of data, only in cases like irrational numbers the different type would matter.

So in short, if you want to return NULL/nil in some cases, you have to use an object type, NOT `int`. If you feel better with using `int`, then the only way would be to use special "invalid" values like `-1` or `-INT_MAX` to let the user know the value is invalid. Or you could throw an exception if that's an option - or just add another method to check if a valid response can be given.

Comment: The problem is that our api is php based... so it can't send obj-c objects. We have to convert from JSON strings to objc objects (using NSJSONSerialization). The return value will either be: `"key":1` or `"key":NULL`. The latter corresponds to a null pointer (e.g. `[NSNull NULL]`).

Comment: then why not simply add an additional line that checks for the character sequence "NULL" and returns NSNull in that case?

Answer (score 1):

If the API doesn't have a user and user_id is the only value returned, why not return a 404 status code with nothing in the body.  Then you just check for status code.  Makes sense, 404 == resource does not exist.  Leverage REST and user your status codes, don't return bogus resources with 200 status codes.

However, if the the user_id is only part of a larger resource being returned (like a relationship to another resource), then NULL is perfectly well justified if no user_id is set for the resource returned.

Comment: It was merely an example... of course the api responds to missing users and such, it was mainly what should happen and how should it be handled that was the question really. :) Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: @ThomasClayson The gist is don't return a bogus resource.  If NULL is a legitmate value for some property of the resource, then using null is fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a status key with the success result of the API call? That's what I always do when creating API responses. It could just be a boolean indicating if it worked or not, or an integer stating what error occurred if it didn't succeed. That way you wouldn't even need to touch the user_id in this example if the API failed.

```
NSNumber *status= [dictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
if(status > 0){
    //succeed
}
else {
   //use status to indicate which error occured
}
```